# Django use Different Serializer based on parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a APIView that provides my model instances. I want to use different serializers based on url parameters, beacause I want to serve different fields based on parameter. I didn't want to use if else check for all situations, so I used a function that provide serializer from serializer objects dict based on type key. Is there a good solution? Does anyone have a better suggestion?
Also what are you thinking about use different endpoints instead of this method.
Here is the code:

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import MySerializerTestView

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:type>', MySerializerTestView.as_view()),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_first = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field_second = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field_third = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

views.py

```
from .models import MyModel
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import MyFirstSerializer,MySecondSerializer,MyThirdSerializer

class MySerializerTestView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        my_data = MyModel.objects.all()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.kwargs['type'],my_data)
        return Response(serializer.data)


    def get_serializer(self,type,data):
        my_serializers = {
        'first':MyFirstSerializer(data,many=True),
        'second':MySecondSerializer(data,many=True),
        'third':MyThirdSerializer(data,many=True),
        }
        return my_serializers[type]
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import MyModel
from rest_framework import serializers

class MyFirstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field_first']

class MySecondSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field_second']


class MyThirdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field_third']
```

Answer (score 6):

You can send a parameter or select the serializer based on the action that is taken.

In your "view.py" file you can use the "get_serializer_class (self)" method to do it.

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if  'parameter' in self.request.query_params:
        return ParameterSerializer

    if self.action == "list" or self.action == 'retrieve':
        return ListSerializer
    else:
        return CreateSerializer
```

Comment: Thanks your advice. But it is not the answer I'm looking for. I don't want to use if else checks. Because there are a lot of possibilities and I have to write if else check for each condition with this method. I'm looking for is there better solution.

Comment: You can adapt it to your needs, you should not necessarily use "If" is just an example.using "self.request.query_params.get ('param', '')" you get the value, which can be an index
for example :
"type = self.request.query_params.get ('param', '')
return my_serializers [type]"