# How to nest abstract relationship in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model called Layer that has a one-to-one relationship with Geometry, and Geometry have the following design:

```
class Geometry(models.Model):
    pass

class Circle(Geometry):
    radius = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Rectangle(Geometry):
    height = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How should I define the Layer serializer to make the layer json contain a property called "geometry" regardless of which child model it has a relationship with? I don't want the property to be called neither circle nor rectangle.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which field do you need in your serializer? If your needs contains submodels, you must define different serializers for each model. Or you can customize any field with SerializerMethodField. If I understood your needs correctly, I want to help you.

Comment: I would like my layer serializer to contain a field called Geometry (a parent model). For example: {"geometry": {radius: 100}} or  {"geometry": {"height": 50, "width": 50}} instead of {"circle": {radius: 100}} or  {"rectangle": {"height": 50, "width": 50}}

Answer (score 0):

You can use seperated serializers for each child models.You can decide with type param which serializer used for geometry key in dict.

```
data = {'geometry': CircleSerializer(circle_model_object).data if type == 'circle' else RectangleSerializer(rectangle_model_object).data}
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to create conditions to decide on which serializer to use. Because I could have 50 different geometries, not only circle and rectangle

Comment: Okey, I understood your problem. Actually I had a question like yours. I didn't find a satisfying solution. Maybe an idea for you,  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60193163/django-use-different-serializer-based-on-parameter). I used a type parameter and created different serializers. I generate a dict that has types as key and serializer classes as value. I detected serializer this method. I hope, it works for you. Also, does your Geometry model have more than fields? Perhaps you can create a foreign key. İt can be more usefull for you.